# Inserting data from a text file to a table

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a text file with following content:

**Output.txt:**

```
windows 32708
linux   30996
macos   32811
```

I am trying with:

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
 Name varchar (100) NOT NULL,
 Memory number (20) NOT NULL,
)

BULK INSERT data FROM 'C:\users\Output.txt' WITH 
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = '|'
ROWTERMINATOR = '|\n'
)
```

\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options.

1. Use [SQL*Loader](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm#SUTIL003) to load the data into some staging table and use procedure to do the data changes (conversion from bytes to GB)
2. Use [External tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10825/et_concepts.htm) to refer to the file and populate your table and do the conversion

Comment: thanks Abhijith..as i have Oracle 10g so  External tables works great for me..:)